# QUERY_STRING is empty, but REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING is normal

Tags: php, query-string

I install Ubuntu server. PHP Version 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4.
In my browser: server.local/catalog?id=250
`$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` has no value
`$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]` has id=250

But in my shared hosting is all ok.
`$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` has id=250
and don't have `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]`

How I can solve this problem? php.ini or apache2.conf?

Comment: Apache config. Compare both.

Comment: apache config is equal

Comment: Are you using .htaccess for URL rewriting? Make sure you also add the Q-flag to send query data.